# Swap EN/FR Language Content with AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have a template in ExactTarget (Salesforce Marketing Cloud), with 2 stacked tables, one `EN` and another `FR`. I need the `EN` to stay at the top and FR at the bottom for `EN` subscribers and `FR` at the top and `EN` at the bottom for `FR` subscribers.

There is a field in the data extension for the Language with 2 possible values, either `EN` or `FR`.

How can I do that with AMPScript? Remember, it's a template with editable fields.

Thanks, VD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can get around this without duplicating at least one of the content areas.  I would use Content Areas as previously suggested, which can be retrieved inside the Template and edited.  I'd also opt for using the [ContentAreaByName()](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions/#ContentAreaByName) function, which is much easier to manage.

**My Contents > Hello_FR**

```
<h1>Bonjour</h1>
```

**My Contents > Hello_EN**

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

**Template**

```
%%[
var @lang
set @lang = AttributeValue("lang")
]%%

<br>@lang: %%=v(@lang)=%%

%%[ if @lang == "EN" then ]%%

  %%[ /* Retrieve from My Contents, Hello_EN and revise */ ]%%
  <custom type="content" name="EN Content 1"> 

%%[ endif ]%%

%%[ /* Retrieve from My Contents, Hello_FR  and revise */ ]%%
<custom type="content" name="FR Content"> 

%%[ if @lang == "FR" then ]%%

  %%[ /* Copy revised content from first Content Area above */ ]%%
  <custom type="content" name="EN Content 2"> 

%%[ endif ]%%
```

The process would be:

1. Create the template
2. Create the base content areas
3. Create the email, based on the template
4. Retrieve the content areas for EN and FR
5. Copy the contents of the first EN content area into to the last
6. Repeat steps 3-5 for each subsequent email

Comment: Thanks Adam but this won't work for the client since they want to edit the content through the WYSIWYG directly in the template edit mode...

Comment: This will allow you to edit the content areas...with the WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: hmm, I just saw now you are using AttributeValue which I never used. Maybe that's the key hehe

Comment: All you'll need to do is set up the template and the create first set of language-specific content areas (as freeform) and then it's just a matter of retrieving the content areas and adjusting them with the WYSIWYG editor.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a content area for each of your tables.  Then, use AMPscript to look up which comes first, Like so:

```
%%[
   SET @contentAreaID_EN = 12321123 /*or whatever value, could use name too */
   SET @contentAreaID_FR = 122342123 /*or whatever value */
   SET @first_content_lang = LOOKUPROWS(VARIABLES_GO_HERE) /*or some other lookup, you only need to do one lookup*/
   VAR @first_area_id, @second_area_id 
   IF(@@first_content_lang == 'EN') THEN
      SET @first_area_id = @contentAreaID_EN
      SET @second_area_id = @contentAreaID_FR
   ELSE
      SET @first_area_id = @contentAreaID_FR
      SET @second_area_id = @contentAreaID_EN
   ENDIF
]%%
```

Then in your email, call each content area

```
%%=ContentArea(I1,S1,B1,S2,N1)=%% 
%%=ContentArea(I1,S1,B1,S2,N1)=%% /* look at our help.exacttarget.com for the specifics of these calls.
```

Good luck!

Comment: thanks Timothy, the problem is the client doesn't wanna deal with Content Areas, they wanna be able to edit everything in the email based on the template using the editable fields...

Comment: @kelly-j-andrews ?

Comment: Then the answer is to put the tables in twice unfortunately, using an if block directly in the email.

Comment: yeah but that will duplicate the client efforts since they have to pour twice the content :(